# congruent modulo S

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, equivalence-relations

This is most likely a silly English question, but in Roman's "Advanced Linear Algebra," on page 21, he writes that:

> Let $S$ be a subset of a commutative ring $R$ with identity. Let $\equiv$ be the binary relation on $R$ defined by $a \equiv b \iff a - b \in S$.  It is easy to see that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation.

Does this mean that $S$ contains the identity of $R$?  I can't see it any other way because if $\equiv$ (as defined) were an equivalence relation, then by reflexivity, $a - a = 0$ must be an element of $S$.  However, the sentence to me sounds like it's saying $R$ is a ring with identity and that we don't know anything about $S$ other than it is a subset of $R$.

Comment: In general by identity of a ring it is meant $1 \in R$ (the multilplicative identity), $0$ is the additive identity.

Comment: For example, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I guess this is a good way to illustrate my confusion.  So $a \in R \implies  a - a = 0 = 2(0) \in 2Z$, $a,b \in Z, a - b \in 2Z \implies -(a-b)=-2c=2d=(b-a) \in 2Z$, etc.  So it's clear that this statement is true for $R=Z,S=2Z$, but what if $S=\{2,5,7\}$?  I feel like $S$ has to be more than just a plain subset of $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is wrong:
$\equiv$ is an equivalence relation iff $S$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $R$.